# Cannot save and revert data using collections after zeroing cells in each iteration

Tags: excel, vba

The checkbox should reset the data in the target cell to zero, and then return it back if it is unchecked. I wanted to store the data between iterations in the collection, however this does not work and all values remain zeros.

Is there any way to store these values in the cells for the duration of the iteration? Please help. Also ignore the colors, the most important thing is to get the zeroing and returning the cell data to work.

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim targetValue As String

    Dim originalValue As Variant
    Dim originalDataCollection As New Collection
    
    targetValue = "СОК"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Лист1") ' Replace with your sheet name
    
    Set originalDataCollection = New Collection
    
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        ' When the checkbox is checked, change the text and background color of matching cells to white
        For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:AE61")
            If cell.Value = targetValue Then
                originalColor = cell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Color
                originalInteriorColor = cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the text color to white
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the background color to white
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the text color to white
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the background color to white
                cell.Offset(0, -3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the text color to white
                cell.Offset(0, -3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the background color to white
                cell.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the text color of the cell on the left to white
                cell.Offset(0, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the background color to white
                
                ' Store the original value of cell.Offset(0, -2)
                originalValue = cell.Offset(0, -2).Value
                originalDataCollection.Add originalValue
                
                ' Set the value of cell.Offset(0, -2) to zero
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = 0
            End If
        Next cell
    Else
        ' When the checkbox is unchecked, reset the text and background color to the original for matching cells
        For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:AE61")
            If cell.Value = targetValue Then
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Font.Color = originalColor
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Reset background color to original
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Font.Color = originalColor
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Reset background color to original
                cell.Offset(0, -3).Font.Color = originalColor
                cell.Offset(0, -3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Reset background color to original
                cell.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = originalColor
                cell.Offset(0, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(152, 212, 84)
                
                 If originalDataCollection.Count > 0 Then
                    cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = originalDataCollection(1)
                    originalDataCollection.Remove 1 ' Remove the first item from the collection
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you declare the collection inside the Sub it will be discarded when the sub exits. I would suggest an 2-d array (or a hidden sheet) would be better than a collection because the array preserves the cell location of the stored values. Also be aware that if you have any "СОК" in columns A to C then `cell.Offset(0, -3)` will fail.

Comment: @CDP1802 And how to add a second array in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare variables outside the Sub to preserve values when the sub exits.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim arData(1 To 61, 1 To 31) 'A1:AE61
Dim arFont(1 To 61, 1 To 31) 'A1:AE61
Dim arInterior(1 To 61, 1 To 31) 'A1:AE61

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long
    Dim targetValue As String

    targetValue = "СОК"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Лист1") ' Replace with your sheet name
    
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        ' When the checkbox is checked
        ' change the text and background color of matching cells to white
        For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:AE61")
        
            ' Store the original value
            r = cell.Row
            c = cell.Column
            arData(r, c) = cell.Value2
            arFont(r, c) = cell.Font.Color
            arInterior(r, c) = cell.Interior.Color
        
            If cell.Value = targetValue Then
                With cell.Offset(0, -3).Resize(, 4)
                   .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the text color to white
                   .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change the background color to white
                End With
                
                ' Set the value of cell.Offset(0, -2) to zero
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = 0
            End If
        Next cell
        MsgBox "Saved"
    Else
        ' When the checkbox is unchecked
        'reset the text and background color to the original for matching cells
        For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:AE61")
            r = cell.Row
            c = cell.Column
            If cell.Value = targetValue Then
                For i = -3 To 0
                    cell.Offset(0, i).Font.Color = arFont(r, c - i)
                    If i = 0 Then
                        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(152, 212, 84)
                    Else
                        cell.Offset(0, i).Interior.Color = arInterior(r, c - i)
                    End If
                    
                    If i = -2 Then
                        cell.Offset(, -2) = arData(r, c - 2)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next cell
        MsgBox "Restored"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Fenroyamas See update - I corrected `If c = 0 Then` to `If i = 0 Then`

Comment: @fenroyamas -  Be aware you can't do any sorting of the data while the checkbox is checked, and if you close the workbook while it's in that state you'll lose the array data....